# Application crashes while reading Serial Ports in loop using .Net 2.0

Tags: vb.net, crash, serial-port, .net-2.0

I take a part on a project and after many tests, me and my colleagues feel little disappointed by our coding skills and methodology. The issue is the following:

The application must read data from some type of RS-485 devices connected on a single bus via one or multiple serial ports. However, these devices come from different manufactures so as a result, they have different connection settings, different command sets and return different data. Moreover, each serial port can handle none, one or multiple devices simultaneously.

Each of our custom COMPort objects contains a device list and each device contains the type and the device settings that are recommended. So, after loading all settings and building all objects, the application starts polling each device in each COMPort object list. Every time, before writing each command, the serial port buffers are emptied and its settings change (Baud-rate, Parity, Handshake) without closing and reopening the port. After every command, a `Threading.Thread.Sleep(delay)` is executed with variable delay, depending on the response time of each device (delay varies from 150ms to 800ms). After Sleep() ends, application Reads the serial port and gets expected data. After that, either if `BytestoRead` > 0 or `BytestoRead` = 0 or an Exception occurs(wrong data returned, error in checksums, etc.), this function returns and application continues to read the next device in the list.

So, application executes in an endless loop, reading all devices from start to end, until it finally ends when user stops it from UI (when the project is a Windows Forms) or when the service Stops (when the project is a Windows service). The application does not use DataReceived event because we faced a lots of trouble, so the Read procedure is done manually.

Finally, application has a global log file which is accessible from all objects and holds all usual and unusual events and each COMPort object has its own log file in which all valid read data are written. Moreover, each COMPort has a timer object which checks for daytime changes per second and everyday at midnight all log files close and new files are opened.

The main problem is that all this seems to work great but unfortunately the application stops writing to logs after 1-2 hours (most of the times after 1:58 minutes exactly on one client machine), then after some minutes it crashes, sometimes with Send or Don't send window and sometimes silently. The CPU load never exceeds 1% and private & virtual memory does not seem to have a leak because it doesn't grow.

I have to mention that this application is tested on 3 machines (Windows XP, Windows 2003), on the following situations: mixed types of devices, one type of device, no devices connected (using null modem cable on one development machine.) Even on the last situation, the application crashes silently. This leads me to the thought that the issue has nothing to do with the Read procedure because in the “no devices attached” scenario, there is no data to be read. Also, the project is built with VB.Net 2008 using .Net Framework 2.0.

**EDIT :** *Below is a small summary of the Read, Write and Polling procedures. I wrote it on Notepad++ as an example because I don't have access to the real code right now, so excuse any syntax errors. The aim of this is to give a better explanation of the situation I describe above and nothing more.*

```
Private deviceIndex as Integer = -1
Private deviceList as List(Of Devices)
Private serialPort as SerialPort()

Private Sub PollSensor()
    Try
        If (deviceIndex <> -1) And deviceIndex > deviceList.Count then
            deviceIndex = 0
        End If

        With serialPort
            If .IsOpen then
                .DiscardInBuffer()
                .DiscardOutBuffer()
                ' SerialPort attributes must change during runtime to suit device requirements.
                ' Some devices require for example 4800 BaudRate and some other 9600.
                .BaudRate = deviceList(deviceIndex).BaudRate
                .Parity = deviceList(deviceIndex).Parity
                .Handshake = deviceList(deviceIndex).HandShake
                ' Write command to device, passing device specific response time.
                ' Some devices have for example 150ms response time and some other 800ms.
                WritetoDevice(new Byte[] {01, 01}, deviceList(deviceIndex).ResponseTime)
            End If
        End With
    Catch ex As Exception
        ' Log
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub WritetoDevice(ByVal command As Byte[], ByVal responseTime As Integer)
    Try
        serialPort.Write(command, 0, command.Length)
        ' Cause application to pause for time equal with the device response time.
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(responseTime)
        ' If device response is regular, data may have been available in serial port.
        If ReadDevice() = 0 then
            ' Poll next device
            deviceIndex += 1
            PollSensor()
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        ' Log
    End Try
End Sub

Private Function ReadDevice() As Integer
    Dim data as String = ""

    Try
        With serialPort
            If .IsOpen then
                If .BytesToRead() > 0 Then
                    Do
                        data += .ReadExisting()
                    Until .BytesToRead() = 0

                    ' Do something with data
                End If
            End If
        End With
    Catch ex As Exception
        ' Log
    Finally
        ' Continue with the next device in deviceList, ignoring the current device Read() result
        ' This happens because devices return faulty data too often and the polling must continue
        Return 0
    End Try
End Function
```

We have tried to use the Debug Diagnostics Tool 1.2 x86 but the results returned, do not help us to understand the source of the issue. Some of the exported reports contain the following, although all exceptions are handled in Try..Catch blocks:

```
 - The following threads in ... are waiting in a WaitOne
 - 6,25% of threads blocked
 - System.ExecutionEngineException
 - System.StackOverflowException
 - System.OutOfMemoryException
 - System.FormatException
 - System.Threading.ThreadAbortException
```

Does anyone have a better idea on how the above scenario could work?

Feel free to criticize any of the above methods, because that will help us to become better.

Comment: More information: when running the app on machine without devices or machine with same type of devices, it crashes exactly after 1h and 9m on one situation and 1h 11m on the other. In additon, application log files are almost of the same size every time it runs until it crashes (~2.229KB)

Comment: The SerialPort in .Net 2.0 - .Net 3.5 was very buggy.  Can you use .Net 4.0 or 4.5?  Don't understand this "Every time, before writing each command, the serial port buffers are emptied and its settings change (Baud-rate, Parity, Handshake)". Why don't you use the DataReceived event handler?

Comment: Thanx for replying. We don't use DataReceived event because the devices that must be read, many times return faulty data, or no data at all. So, many times readTimeouts occured or data from different devices arrive together as one and this was a mess. Also, each device needs different port settings e.g. 9600, 8, 1 ,Even and 4800, 8, 1, None but they are connected on a single bus (RS485) and arrive on serial port converted to RS232 protocol.

Comment: I don't think you need our help to "criticize any of the above methods", you already know that this program is *seriously* buggy and uses about all the bad practices you can ever pick.  Start by stopping to hide the inconvenient truths and remove all exception swallowing code.  Also seriously consider hiring a skilled consultant to review the code.

Comment: Sna, with no code posted it is hard to comment on anything (whether that be bugs or good bad practices).  Post some code and then maybe we can provide some feedback.  We can only guess if there is no code.

Comment: @HansPassant Thank you for your suggestion. However, I admit it's buggy until now, but I don't agree at all that it uses all the bad practices anybody could pick. At all. I respect your opinion but this is a non commercial project so hiring someone could be our first option.

Comment: @tcarvin You are right but I think it would be wrong to post only the Read() and Write() procedures because it wouldn't make sense. The whole project is about 5000 lines, so I tried to explain the issue in general. I 'll try to modify the useless info and post the main code.

Comment: Focus on the read code, the write code, any p/invoke or threading code.  These are likely candidates.

Comment: We replaced the Treading.Thread.Sleep() and modified the code to work with System.Threading.Timer() object. The application seems to run without hanging, crashing or having memory leaks for about 4 hours. I 'll come back tomorrow with more comments about this.